# Can a Python generator be easily saved and reloaded from disk?

Tags: python, serialization, generator

Is there a way to serialize a generator, current state and all (local variables, etc), so that you can load the string containing the serialized generator later and be able to pick up right from where the last yield statement exited the function?  If yes and you know of a web page with a code sample, please share a link to it.

Comment: Googling gave me this link http://bugs.python.org/issue1092962 .. so the generators are not pickle-able (unless you send a clean patch to Python developers). But there might be some clues how to do this in the discussions of that issue.

Comment: @mkorpela.  Thanks, at least I have a starting point now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should check out [`generator_tools`](http://www.fiber-space.de/generator_tools/doc/generator_tools.html)' [`picklegenerator`](http://www.fiber-space.de/generator_tools/doc/generator_tools.html#mozTocId742105).

You might also find this article useful: http://metaoptimize.com/blog/2009/12/22/why-cant-you-pickle-generators-in-python-workaround-pattern-for-saving-training-state/

Comment: That last url is dead :(

Answer (score 7):

Stackless Python is able to pickle generators.
Or you could try PyPy 1.7, which also implements many stackless features, including pickling of generators and functions.

Code snippet: http://pastebin.com/p4RkVQkJ

Stackless Python 3.2 and 2.7.2 could be downloaded here: http://zope.stackless.com/download/sdocument_view

PyPy 1.7 could be downloaded here: http://pypy.org/download.html