# Transfer a python generator across a network

Tags: python, sockets, generator

Is there a way to transfer a generator across a network?  Suppose I have function that randomly subsets an array

```
def random_array_generator(array, n):
    rows = np.random.randint(0 , array.shape[0], n)
    sliced_array = array[rows]
    yield sliced_array
```

and then

```
data = random_array_generator(some_array, 100)
```

Is there a way to send `data` to a remote server?  I constructed a basic TCP client/server connection using `socket` but `s.send()` requires a buffer or string.  Apologies if thinking I could put a generator as the input of that function is absurd.

Comment: oh no please don't apologize for thinking something absurd (you didn't anyway). that a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778340/can-a-python-generator-be-easily-saved-and-reloaded-from-disk), it might be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You can use [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). Specifically, [`pickle.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps), which returns the serialized object as a string, so you can send it via socket. If you're running Python 2.x, consider using [`cPickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle) instead, it's much faster.

However, it seems like you can't serialize generators (at least with `pickle`), so consider using a list or tuple.

Hope it helps.